# Should I default the environment for someone using my library?

Tags: api, default, environment

I have been having this debate with a friend where i have a library (its python but I didn't include that as a tag as the question is applicable to any language) that has a few dependencies. The debate is whether to provide a default environment in the initialization or force the user of the code to explicitly set one.

My opinion is to force the user as its explicit and will avoid confusion and make it clear what they are pointing to.

My friend this is safer and more convenient to default to an environment and let the user override if he wants to.

Thoughts ? Are there any good references or examples / patterns in popular libraries that support either of our arguments?  also, any popular blogs or articles that discuss this API design point?

Comment: Similar musings to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166539/do-you-find-convention-over-configuration-good-or-bad

Comment: @mguymon - i think its a slightly different topic.

Comment: Target audience is another large factor to consider.  Is it something internal to one company vs anyone on the net? For users with a designer mindset vs engineering mindset? Etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have any references, but here are my thoughts as a potential user of said library.

I think it's good to have a default configuration available to allow developers to quickly evaluate the library.  I don't want to have to go through a bunch of configuration just to see if the library will do what I need.  Once I'm happy that the library will do what i need it to do, then I'm happy to configure it the way I want.

A good example is Microsoft's ASP.Net MVC framework.  When you create a new MVC project it hooks in a default authentication and membership provider, which allows the developer to very quickly get a functioning application up and running.  It is also easy to configure different providers to be used if the default one's don't meet the requirements of the application in question.

As a slightly different example, Atlassian Confluence is wiki software which supports many different back-end databases.  Atlassian could have chosen to have no default DB configuration, but instead Confluence ships with a default, simple, file-based database to allow users to evaluate the software.  For production installations you can then hook up to Oracle, SQL Server, mySQL or whatever else you like.

There may be instances where a default configuratino for a library doesn't really make sense, but I think that would be a special case, rather than a general rule.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.  If you can provide sensible defaults, you might want to do that: it will make life easer on the occasional user of the library as they can set only the relevant settings, as opposed to the whole environment (with possibly settings the implications of which they don't fully understand (yet)).  You are correct, that in situations it is possible this leads to frustration and confusion as the defaulted settings might cause unexpected behavior (unexpected by the (inexperienced) user) -- you have to weigh the reduced frustration of convenience against the price of not-understood defaults to make the choice for each of these possible-to-default settings, which choice might affect the choice for other, related settings as well

On the other hand, if there is no sensible default (e.g. DB credentials, remote address), you should require the user to provide those settings.

The key in both cases is to provide enough information in the documentation of the library and in the error messages (either for missing settings or conflicting ones) that the user can figure out what those settings actually mean/control without having to read through the source code of the library.  This part is hard because 1) it is usally tedious from the point of view of the library developer (so it is often skimped) and 2) the documentation has to be written from the mindset of a newbie to the library, which is often different from the library developer's mindset -- the latter knows the implicit connections/implications, the former has to be told about those in an understandable way.

Answer (score 1):

Although not exactly identical in terms of problem domain, this strikes me as the [Convention over Configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) argument.

There has been quite a lot momentum behind CoC in recent years, and in my mind, it makes a whole lot of sense.  As long as flexibility is not lost, you have everything to gain.  Lower friction development is what we are all after, and if I've got to configure every aspect of your API in order to get it working, I'm less inclined to use it over another API of equal functionality.

I happen to like Hanselman's podcasts, so if you want a little light listening, check out [this podcast](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast167ConventionOverConfigurationWithJeremyMiller.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think your question needs some clarification. For starters, I don't think a library should have any runtime configuration. In terms of dependencies, library dependencies should be handled in a manner appropriate to the environment they are being written for. In python, those dependencies should be in the setup.py file (under requirements), and ultimately that file should meet the requirements of whatever service you plan on making it available on (i.e. pypi for python).

For applications, it is completely okay to require runtime configuration, but you should try to have sensible defaults. If your application depends on libraries, that dependency should be handled in the same way a library dependency would be handled, even though that information may be redundant in the context of an installer (if needed). For the most part first-run scripts and their ilk should be apart of the installer/rpm.

For Web Frameworks, it is typical that your app would carry configuration with it, and likely that it would need to be installed in a different way than traditional applications. Here, about the only thing you can do is try to follow the conventions of whatever framework you are writing in.